# If-statement inside jquery Append()

Tags: jquery, html, json, append

Inside my jquery Append() I wan't to run an IF-statement to include an image on all my objects except on the first one.

Like:

```
var i = 0;

$('#divDetailsForSelectedInfo').append(
    '<div class="roundedAndBoxShade leftResultObject" id = "' + value.Query.Id + '">'+
    '<div class="leftResultObject_inner">' +
if (i > 0){
   <img src="/img.jpg"/>;
}
'<div>asdf</div>');
```

The code is generated by Json+Jquery and then it is all appended on a div in my index-file.
As far as I've been able to tell through immence google-ing this can't be done, but I might be wrong?

If it is indeed "impossible", could the :first selector in Jquery be used in some cool way?

Comment: Wait: where are you incrementing `i`, and *why* would an `id`-based selector return multiple elements?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

A simpler solution:

```
var i = 0;
$('#somediv').append(
    'html before' + 
    (i > 0 ? '<img src="/img.jpg"/>': '') +
    'more html'
);
```

Answer (score 7):

```
var i = 0;
var str=''
if (i > 0){
  str =  '<img src="/img.jpg"/>;'
}
$('#divDetailsForSelectedInfo').append(
    '<div class="roundedAndBoxShade leftResultObject" id = "' + value.Query.Id + '">'+
    '<div class="leftResultObject_inner">' +str+'<div>asdf</div>');
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I can think of to do this:

```
$('#divDetailsForSelectedInfo').append(
    function(i) {
        return '<div class="roundedAndBoxShade leftResultObject" id = "' + value.Query.Id + '">' + '<div class="leftResultObject_inner">' + (i > 0 ? '<img src="/img.jpg"/>' : '');
    });
```

[JS Fiddle proof-of-concept](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/6qAbZ/1/).