# jQuery How To Use Backticks In Append

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, frontend

I wanted to interpolate variables in strings in JS so I used ``(backticks) as shown here -
[How To Interpolate Variables In String in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304014/how-to-interpolate-variables-in-strings-in-javascript-without-concatenation)

Then, I Wanted To put IF-Statements in jQuery Append So I got this -
[IF Statements In jQuery Append](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12898400/if-statement-inside-jquery-append/12898733)

But When I use Both Together , Backticks Don't Output Text As Usual-

```
$("main").append(`Hello ${my_var}`+(second_var>1?"hi ":"bye")+`Bye ${my_var})`
```

This Results Only In "hi" , The Backticks Before And After The Ternary Operator Don't Output Anything.
HELP ??

Comment: I see an append function without a closing parentheses :)

Comment: @code that was to represent my problem here , not the real code .. but closed it anyway

Comment: The closing parenthesis is still wrong. We can't help if you don't show us your real code. Don't write it out here, copy-paste what you have, simplifiy if necessary.  Anything on your browser's devtools console?

Comment: I have added the answer. Let me know if it solves your problem.

Comment: Your code, as provided with some minor fixes, works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/uvx52qwt/

Comment: Thank you everyone , I made a mistake , apologies for that . Thank you for making my experience on StackOverflow great .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like the below.

```js
const my_var = "Name";
const seconde_var = 2;
console.log(`Hello ${my_var} ${seconde_var >1 ? "hi": "bye"} bye ${my_var}`);
```